# Laravel 5.2 ajax code doesn't work

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I developed a simple ajax code.According to this image when click+ qty increase and when click - qty decrease
[image]

Code in online _help.blade.php

```
<head>
      <title>Ajax Example</title>
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script>


           $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.cart_quantity_up, .cart_quantity_down').on('click', function(e) {
                       e.preventDefault();

    var increment = $(this).data('increase');
    var itemId = $('.cart_quantity_input').val();
                    $.ajax({
                          type:'post',
                          url:'getmsg',
                         dataType:'json', 
                         data:{
                          'item_id': itemId,
                          'increase': increment

                         },
                       success:function(data){
                     $("cart_quantity_input").val(data.qty);
                                     }   }); 
                                        });
               });
     </script>

</head>


<body>


 <div class="cart_quantity_button">
    <a class="cart_quantity_up" href="javascript:void(0)" data-increase="1" > + </a>
    <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="{{1}}" autocomplete="off" size="2">
    <a class="cart_quantity_down" href="javascript:void(0)" data-increase="0" > - </a>
</div>

    </body>
<footer>

<script type="text/javascript">
       var csrf_token   =   $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
           $.ajaxSetup({
             headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrf_token}
                       });
     </script>
</script>
</footer>
```

Code in controller function

```
public function ajaxl(Request $request)
   {
         if ($request->ajax()) {
             $id = $request->item_id;

           if ($request->increase) {
                 //$cart->increment('qty');
            $qty = 2;

             } else {
                 //$cart->decrement('qty');
              $qty = 0;
             }
              //echo"hello ajaxlara:";


      return response()->json(array('qty'=> $id), 200);
                                }
    }
```

And this routes.php

```
Route::get('/ajax',function(){return view('online_help');});
Route::post('/getmsg','Hello@ajaxl');
```

When I click + or - the value doesn't change and no error.
Please any one help me

Comment: what's about csrf? do you have it or not?

Comment: I added it and test it ,it work with a simple code

Comment: I can't see any csrf in the code you wrote here, if you don't use it, then you need to disable the VerifyCsrfToken middleware

Comment: I added it in the head and footer But the problem isn't in csrf as i test it

Comment: how do you know? you added it in the head, but you also must include it in the ajax request, e.g.         headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }

Comment: I already added it in the footer section  as https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token  and this part work

Comment: The error in ajax code not in csrf

Comment: so, can we see the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121501/discussion-between-azhar-nabil-and-vitr).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very small.

This line:

```
$("cart_quantity_input").val(data.qty);
```

just you forgot to add . before cart_quantity_input
So change it to be :
    $(".cart_quantity_input").val(data.qty);